# Reset Active Subnav using Bootstrap Data-Hover State

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap data-hover plugin as linked below.

I have two levels of navigation when you mouseover each item in the navigation the sub-navigation is supposed to appear. That is working fine.

The issue I am having is that I want the sub-navigation of the active section to reappear if no other sub-navigation is showing.

I added the JS below which is making every item after the active item work correctly but every Item before the active one as well as the active one is not working correctly.

The Items before the active one are resetting to the active sub-navigation when I try to go from the Main Nav Item to it's own Sub-navigation

When I mouseout of the Main Navigation Item it does not add the open class to it causing the sub-navigation to go away.

HTML

```
<ul class="main-section-nav nav navbar-nav">
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a>item</a>    
  <ul>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="dropdown active open">
  <a>item</a>    
  <ul>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
  </ul>
 </li> 
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a>item</a>    
  <ul>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
  </ul>
 </li>  
 <li class="dropdown">
  <a>item</a>    
  <ul>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
    <li> item </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main-section-nav > li').mouseout(function(){
      $('.active').addClass('open');
    });
   });
```

https://cameronspear.com/blog/bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-plugin/

Comment: Are you saying if the nav the user is looking at doesn't have a sub-nav menu, you want the active menu's sub-nav to show up?

Comment: If the user is not looking at any nav items then the active menu's subnav should show up. Every nav Item has sub-nav.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.mouseleave` instead

```
$('.main-section-nav > li').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.active').addClass('open');
});
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/CSS_Apprentice/xadrbp7m/2/

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout):

> The mouseout event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child
>   elements as well the selected element.
>
> The mouseleave event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves
>   the selected element.

Comment: This Fixed the issue with the items before the active but unfortunately did not fix the current navigation issue.

I think that my mouseleave is firing before the data-hover is which is adding 'open' before removing it.

Comment: We could do an if else then. if something already hasClass `'open'` = do  nothing. else = addClass `'open'` to active

Comment: I have to leave the office now. I'll try it when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Bad HTML issue

**This:**

```
<ul class="class="main-section-nav nav navbar-nav>
```

**Should Be This:**

```
<ul class="main-section-nav nav navbar-nav">
```

Comment: That was just a typo in my question asking. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There's more bad HTML there too ul not closed, and li double closed. Is it for sure not a typo issue?

Comment: I typed all that trying to replicate my code. It is definitely a logic issue.